# Check number format in ruby

Tags: ruby

In one of my tests I want to check whether a value is an eight-digit number between 0-9 and make it more generic, how can I do this in Ruby?

Example: 36756786, 38796809 etc.

Comment: Regular expressions will help.

Comment: make it more generic? What do you mean with that?

Comment: An eight-digit number is not between zero and nine.

Comment: What did you write to solve the problem? It's easier for us to fix your code than to write code for you. Also, it's important to supply some samples of the text you're working with, to we know if the numbers are embedded in other text, or are by themselves on lines, etc.

Comment: "An eight-digit number is not between zero and nine." But `00000000` and `00000009` are. :-)

Comment: @theTinMan I thought someone may say that. I assumed zero is not used redundantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
numberString =~ /\A(\d){8}\Z/
```

Comment: @Kayen: Sure. Glad I could help. If the answer helped you, make sure to accept it.